# Importing from node_modules in Stylus with Laravel Mix

Tags: webpack, stylus, laravel-mix

I have a large Stylus project I need to port into Laravel Mix from vanilla Gulp.

The `app.styl` includes another `framework.styl` which `@import`s stuff from node_modules. I can't use the `use` and `import` flags (or at least I can't figure out how to) in Laravel Mix, because

1. For some dependencies, I only need to import specific files inside the node_modules folder, not the whole thing
2. With one dependency, I need to set a long list of variables inside of Stylus *before* importing it.

#### main.styl

```
@import "includes/framework.styl"

/* Other stuff */
```

#### includes/framework.styl

```
$variable = 1.5
$other = white
/* bunch more */

@import "jeet"
@import "foo/src/specific.styl"

ks-no-conflict = true
@import "kouto-swiss"

/* other stuff */
```

All of the `@import`s in `framework.styl` are from node_modules. The order in which these dependencies and files are loaded is important, as they can clash with one another if loaded in the wrong order.

However, when I run `npm run dev`, it complains it can't find any of the dependency locations inside `framework.styl`.

I've tried prefixing the `@import` paths with `~/`, `node_modules/`,  `./node_modules/`, `../../../../node_modules`, etc.; nothing seems to work. It all leads to:

```
failed to locate @require file node_modules/jeet/styl/index.styl
```

With `../../../../node_modules` and `../../../node_modules`, I get the following;

```
Module build failed: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
```

How can I either make Stylus find these dependencies in node_modules (my preferred solution), or in the alternative, replicate the above in Laravel Mix options?